# How to get values from Entry on tkinter?

Tags: tkinter, tk-toolkit, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-entry

if I run this program I can't seem to get any values on my user entries. Also, I am not sure why my Tkinter is producing 2 windows. Can anyone help?

Here is the sample code.

Background: I am making an interactive app for the Lorenz Equations to show the chaotic butterfly trajectory in phase space. In my Tkinter window, I have added 3 Entry for the user to choose for a certain parameter and I want to retrieve these values but for some reason, under function click1, it is not printing the values obtained.

```
import sys
import traceback
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from random import randint
import math
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib 

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib import style

matplotlib.use("TkAgg")

class LorenzAttractorRungeKutta(tk.Frame):
    DT            = 1e-3     # Differential interval
    STEP          = 100000   # Time step count

    def __init__(self):
        global user_r_entry
        global user_sigma_entry
        global user_b_entry

        super(LorenzAttractorRungeKutta, self).__init__()

        self.X_0, self.Y_0, self.Z_0 = 0,0,0

        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.grid()
        self.root.title("Lorenz Simulation")
        self.root.geometry = ("500x500")
        self.root.resizable = (False, False)

        self.res = [[], [], []]

        self.root.graphframe = LabelFrame(master = self.root, text = "Phase Space")
        self.root.label1 = Label(self.root.graphframe, text="Graph", height = 3, width = 15).grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=10)

        #self.root.graphframe = LabelFrame(master = self.root, text = "Phase Space")
        #self.root.label1 = Label(self.root.graphframe, text="Graph", height = 3, width = 15).grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=10)
        user_r_entry = IntVar()
        r_entry = Entry(self.root, textvariable = user_r_entry).grid(row = 1, column = 0)
        self.root.r_label = Label(self.root, text="r value", height = 1, width = 12).grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=1)

        user_sigma_entry = IntVar()
        sigma_entry = Entry(self.root, textvariable = user_sigma_entry).grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        self.root.sigma_label = Label(self.root, text="sigma value", height = 1, width = 12).grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=1)

        user_b_entry = IntVar()
        b_entry = Entry(self.root, textvariable = user_b_entry).grid(row = 1, column = 2)
        self.root.b_label = Label(self.root, text="b value", height = 1, width = 12).grid(row=2, column=2, columnspan=1)

        self.plot_button = Button (self.root, command = self.click1, height = 2, width = 4).grid(row = 3, column = 1)

        self.mainloop()


    def click1(self):
        global r_info
        global sigma_info
        global b_info

        r_info = user_r_entry.get()
        sigma_info = user_sigma_entry.get()
        b_info = user_b_entry.get()

        print (r_info, sigma_info, b_info)

    def plot(self):
        global user_r_entry
        global user_sigma_entry
        global user_b_entry
        global r_info
        global sigma_info
        global b_info

        print (r_info,sigma_info,b_info)

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, self.root)

        try:
            xyz = [self.X_0, self.Y_0, self.Z_0]
            for _ in range(self.STEP):
                k_0 = self.__lorenz(xyz)
                k_1 = self.__lorenz([x + k * self.DT / 2 for x, k in zip(xyz, k_0)])
                k_2 = self.__lorenz([x + k * self.DT / 2 for x, k in zip(xyz, k_1)])
                k_3 = self.__lorenz([x + k * self.DT for x, k in zip(xyz, k_2)])
                for i in range(3):
                    xyz[i] += (k_0[i] + 2 * k_1[i] + 2 * k_2[i] + k_3[i]) \
                            * self.DT / 6.0
                    self.res[i].append(xyz[i])

            #print (self.res[1])

            f = Figure(figsize=(10,10), dpi=100)
            a = f.add_subplot(111)
            a.plot(self.res[0], self.res[1])


            canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, self)
            canvas.draw()
            canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        except Exception as e:
            raise

    def __lorenz(self, xyz):
        global r_info
        global sigma_info
        global b_info

        p = sigma_info
        r = r_info
        b = b_info

        try:
            return [
                -p * xyz[0] + p * xyz[1],
                -xyz[0] * xyz[2] + r * xyz[0] - xyz[1],
                xyz[0] * xyz[1] - b * xyz[2]
            ]
        except Exception as e:
            raise



if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        LorenzAttractorRungeKutta()

    except Exception as e:
        traceback.print_exc()
        sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: Why do you think you can't get the value? What happens when you try? If you are getting an error, please include the error in your question. Also, since the question is about fetching the value from an entry widget, it seems that matplotlib isn't required _for this question_. Please remove it and reduce the code down to a [mcve].

Comment: Also, please give us your ouput, because not everyone has matplotlib installed. Thanks!